# calculate Similarity of two adverbs or two adjectives

Tags: nlp, similarity, wordnet, cosine-similarity, wsd

I want to write a program to calculate the similarity of two adverbs or two adjectives, but The WordNet has not ontology structure for adverb and adjective.

At the first try, I used The Adapt-lesk algorithm. The result of this algorithm is very disappointing for adverb or adjective. What is the best way to calculate similarity of these? please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is rare but `WordNet` have a relation call `pertainym`. It  connects the relevant adjective to its adverbial form. If you've NLTK (http://nltk.org/) installed and using python you can try this example below:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> for ss in wn.all_synsets(): # loop through all synsets in WordNet
...     for l in ss.lemmas: # loop through the possible lemmas in that synsets.
...             x = j.pertainyms() # access lemma's pertainyms
...             if len(x) > 0:
...                     print str(ss.offset)+"-"+ss.pos, l, x
```